# VS2010 - Project References

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am currently going through and updating references in projects as their locations have changed.

Is there any way to discern by looking at the properties dialog (or some other convenient place) which references are project references and which are binary? I have been having to go to Add References and check there to see what is referenced but it's a pain when dealing with a a lof of projects.

Comment: Might be easiest to open up the raw text of the .csproj files and navigate to the reference section of that file.

Comment: I tried that too. I was really hoping someone could point how to differentiate when looking at the properties window when the reference is selected.

Comment: If it is a project, in the properties window, it will not contain a "Specific Version" property.

Comment: Kevin after a cursory look I believe that you just might be right! If you put it into an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @KevinCrowell Great tip! As Mike says, that should be put in an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a project, in the properties window, it will not contain a "Specific Version" property. This is the case since a project reference is always controlled by the version of the project being referenced. It just automatically updates as the referenced project updates.

Otherwise, you could open up the raw text of the .csproj files and navigate to the reference section of the file.